# ¿Como pasar el entorno virtual a producción?

Tags: python, virtualenv, desarrollo

¿Cómo puedo pasar el proyecto con el entorno virtual a otro ordenador para ponerlo en producción?
Actualmente, tengo la carpeta compartida en el de producción (server?), cuando necesito ejecutarlo en éste, lo hago como si lo hiciera en el de desarrollo, también tiene python como es lógico, pero desde el de desarrollo, abro el cmd, el entorno virtual y el VSC, desde la unidad mapeada de la carpeta compartida.
No me surgen muchos problemas de esta forma, pero no creo que sea la forma más óptima de hacerlo, me gustaría saber si hay algo mejor. Todo es de forma personal, no lo voy a subir a ningún servidor, ni nada, es solo para mi. Son dos pcs físicos.
¿hay otra forma de hacerlo mas óptima y fiable?
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: No se si te refieres a `virtualenv`, pero en todo caso lo suyo es crear el fichero de requisitos (`requirements.txt`) en tu entorno virtual usando [`pip freeze > requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/), crear luego el entorno virtual en el PC destino, copiar el fichero de requisitos y hacer la instalación de los requisitos con `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Así ambos entornos serian iguales y podrías copiar tus ficheros de scripts. Pero más allá de esto, lo suyo sería tener un repositorio `git` que puedas usar para este propósito. Saludos

Comment: "más óptima y fiable" -> A ver, más fiable que lanzar el archivo directamente?? No, no hay manera más fiable. Más óptima? Puedes tenerlo completamente automatizado con un servicio para que en el momento en que se caiga se vuelva a lanzar, o que se actualice cada vez que haces cambios en el código... todo depende de cómo lo tengas montado, qué SO estés usando... hay muchas variables. Lo primero es meter el código en un sistema de control de versiones como git, tener un repositorio centralizado (por ejemplo github) y con eso ya te ahorras andar copiando y pegando entre máquinas.

Comment: Gracias. Si me refiero al virtualenv. Creia que con hacer el pip install en el de desarrollo era suficiente, ya que, los dos ordenadores-python, apuntan a la misma carpeta, solo difiere la unidad o letra (D:/..etc) ademas cuando hago el pip install en el de producción, me arroja de que ya estan actualizados los requisitos.

Comment: La carpeta de tu proyecto si ya tiene un entorno virtual, con sus paquetes propios es fácilmente "portable", copias la mismas y seguramente tengas que modificar el activate si hay que reapuntar la unidad. Mi única dudas, es en Linux, no recuerdo si virtualenv copia el interprete o hace enlaces al interprete del sistema.  Sino el procedimiento en producción sería el mismo que usaste en desarrollo: 1) crear entorno virtual 2) Instalar requirements.txt. De cualquier manera te comento que python desde hace un tiempo ya incorporó la funcionalidad similar  a la de virtualenv, no necesitas usarlo.

Comment: Los entornos ya los tengo montados y funcionando a través, como he indicado de una carpeta compartida. Tengo la duda de que si hago un pip install de un paquete en el de desarrollo, este se vea reflejado en el de produccion sin que en éste último tenga que hacer nada,  se copiara lo que corresponda en el entorno virtual que esta en comun. Mi duda, es si es mejor tener todo en local del desarrollo y luego pasarlo al de produccion.